# Migrating a svn repo to git. Multiple app in svn repo need to broken into separate git repos

Tags: svn, git, migration

I have a svn repo with various apps as subdirectory of a single svn repo. That worked because I could have checked out a partial, repo. As I cant do that with git obviously I need multiple  repos. I want to keep my commit histories in the git export. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to specify the root directory for cloning. You can do it like this:

```
git svn clone svn://repository/subdirectory_of_app1 app1
git svn clone svn://repository/subdirectory_of_app2 app2
...
```

If you have trunk/branches/tags folders in each of the app folders, you can also add additional arguments:

```
git svn clone svn://repository/subdirectory_of_app1 -T trunk -t tags -b branches app1
...
```

Comment: This also worked great for me, and you can also synchronize your git commits back to the svn repository.